# Is it possible to print a byte array on a printer in npm like in java with DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

I am replacing an old java application with an electron app. In the old application, we opened the cash drawer of a cash register by printing a byte array with a DocFlavor DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE

Is it possible to do the same thing with an npm package?

Comment: The question does not make any sense. An npm package is simply a bundling of code for use in an application. It doesn't actually do anything. If you're asking for someone to find you an npm package with code that allows you to "print a byte array with a DocFlavor", then that is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is a `DocFlavor`?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Cash Drawer
byte[] CD_KICK_2 = {0x1b,0x70,0x00}; // Sends a pulse to pin 2 []                  
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;                
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

try {
  Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(CD_KICK_2, flavor, null);
  job.print(doc, null);                       
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed - it looks like you might have had some trouble formatting your code? Also it's usually good to write a little to give some context for your answer and an overview of how / why it works.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, this is what we are doing now in java but we are looking for the same thing in js with npm